# Question about Rings, Homomorphisms and Ideals.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

Let $\mathbb{Z}[i]= \{a+bi: a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$be a ring. The ideal $\langle 5 \rangle= \{a+bi: a,b \in \mathbb{Z},  5\mid a$ and $5\mid b \}$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$??

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

I've tried to make a homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 5 \rangle$ and $\mathbb{Z}_m$, for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, if $m$ is a prime number we have a field $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 5 \rangle$ and $\langle 5 \rangle$ is maximal ideal. For otherwise, if $m$ is not a prime number $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 5 \rangle$ is not a field therefore $\langle 5 \rangle$ is not maximal.

However, it's hard to make a homomorphism between that rings (yes, I've tried m=5) and of course, I've tried to use the homomorphism theorem...

Can you help me??? What is the homomorphism?

Comment: An element of $\Bbb Z[i]$ is divisible by $5$ if and only if its real and imaginary parts are, therefore $\Bbb Z[i]/\langle 5\rangle$ has $25$ elements. Therefore, the only possible choice for an isomorphism $\Bbb Z[i]/\langle 5\rangle\to \Bbb Z_m$ is for $m=25$. Of course, if you want to go down that road, you should also consider the possibility of $\Bbb Z[i]/\langle 5\rangle$ being isomorphic to finite rings of order $25$ which are not in the form $\Bbb Z_m$ for any $m\in\Bbb N$: namely $\Bbb Z_5\times \Bbb Z_5$ or $\Bbb F_{25}$.

Comment: By the way, you consistently mention *homo*morphisms (instead of *iso*morphisms), but I don't see how that is supposed to help. In fact, for all non-zero rings $R$ and ideals $I$ there is a field $k$ and a (surjective) homomorphism $R/I\to k$: just compose the quotient map with the quotient map by a maximal ideal of $R/I$. But of course most ideals are not maximal.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID. Thus, an ideal $0 \neq I = (x)$ is prime if and only if it is maximal, if and only if $x$ is prime (which for PIDs, coincides with the notion of irreducible).

Your question boils down to "Is $5$ prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

> Note that $5 = (1+2i)(1-2i)$ and so $(5) \subsetneq (1+2i) \subsetneq \mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

This means that $5$ is irreducible in $\mathbf Z[i]$.  However note that in this ring
$$5=(2-i)(2+i),$$
and if $5$ were irreducible, one of  .these factors would be a unit in the ring.